# Revert Apple Clang Version For NVCC

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cuda, clang

I am trying to run NVCC to compile a CUDA program on my Mac.

When I try to run NVCC, I am receiving the following error: "nvcc fatal   : The version ('70300') of the host compiler ('Apple clang') is not supported".

I recently updated my XCode version to 7.3, and my Mac to 10.11.4.

Is there any way to revert my Clang Version?

Comment: An update: CUDA 7.5.27 has been released. It now works with Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29) on Mac OS 10.11.4.

Comment: does not work with the new xcode 8

Comment: @GeorgHeiler this helped me: https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/issues/318#issuecomment-295555763

Answer (score 46):

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com/downloads/, log in and then download http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.11_for_Xcode_7.2/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.11_for_Xcode_7.2.dmg, and install, as was suggested by fabregaszy.
2. Run the following command to switch to the old version:
   `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`
3. Run the following command to quickly check clang version:
   `clang --version`

Comment: Thank you! By the way, if you've already done an upgrade to 8.0 before you don't need to do step (1), you can just run the second command here. That brought my clang to 7.3 and things work now.

Comment: This 'worked' but my installation (of `cutorch`) was still failing. The thing I was missing was that I had cached versions still hanging around. In my case, I hadn't run `make clean`/`clean.sh`.
Thanks to subzerofun on github - 
https://github.com/torch/cutorch/issues/522#issuecomment-252517776

Comment: This worked on my mac 10.12.5 (sierra). 
[Link To CMT 7.3](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.11_for_Xcode_7.3/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.11_for_Xcode_7.3.dmg)

Thank you

Comment: how do you switch back :)

Comment: This `reverts`, it does not switch to a specific version, and is only relevant for this specific case.  Can you provide a more general solution?

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer says to download the next-to-latest command line tools and install them, then select them by typing in the console

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Its been asked how to revert to the original version of the tools. This is achieved by

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Answer (score 7):

I just had the same issue after upgrading to XCode 7.3 on 10.11. Reinstalling the previous (7.2) command line tools didn't downgrade the default clang compiler. To fix this I used a previous XCode.app package to rename and copy the XcodeDefault.xctoolchain directory into the Toolchains director in the current /Applications/Xcode.app. You have to right click on Xcode.app to "Show package contents" then browse to the Toolchains dir.

[image]

Then (re)start Xcode, hit command-, for preferences, then go to locations. You will see the dropdown for Command Line Tools. Change this to the version of the toolchain you copied over.

[image]

You can check the default version of clang in Terminal:

```
clang -v OR llvm-gcc -v
```

Now nvcc should work

Comment: Can you please tell where did you get the previous xCode.app from? When I download it from the Apple's site, it is an installation package, and I don't want it to be installed on my system.

Comment: log into your apple developer account, then click here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ this site has the legacy xcode dmgs. Down to at least 6.4 contains the Xcode.app file.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, already figured that out. I tried to cheat and download just the command line tools, but they were installable package, so I couldn't extract clang from them.

Answer (score 4):

I came into the same issue.

I think the old command-line tools which can be downloaded from 
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

may solve this issue.

**Updated:**

I downloaded from the link below and installed, the clang version was successfully reverted to Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 clang-700. But please keep an eye on your OS X version.

http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.11_for_Xcode_7.2/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.11_for_Xcode_7.2.dmg

Comment: When I click on this page, it says it cannot be found. Is there a more up to date one?

Comment: @JudeMichaelMurphy It seems that you need to login with an apple developer account via https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

I would try homebrew's version of llvm, it works for me.
`brew install llvm37`

Then, set your compiler to homebrew's clang:
/usr/local/bin/clang++-3.7 or whatever respondes to
`which clang++-3.7`

That way you can leave your OS X dev environment defaults as they are.

Comment: How do you set your compiler to homebrew's clang? I've tried putting `/usr/local/bin` first in my PATH and setting `ln -s clang++-3.7 clang` but I get the same error.

Comment: I wouldn't hard-link using brew, it's messy to say the least. Change your "configure" or "cmake" variables to use the compiler in the Cellar. My path to clang is /usr/local/Cellar/llvm37/3.7.1/bin/clang++-3.7. Common variables are CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER and CUDA_HOST_COMPILER for cmake.

Comment: `ln -s clang++-3.7 clang` just points "clang++-3.7" TO "clang" - does you no good. Linking is FROM -> TO, not vice-versa. Also, your links can be relative or absolute - I prefer absolute, but, wouldn't use symlinks in this case.

Comment: This is the only sensible answer here, it should have more upvotes

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, installing Command Line Tools from X-code version 7.2. currently is not solving this.

Trying to compile results in:

`nvcc fatal   : GNU C/C++ compiler is no longer supported as a host compiler on Mac OS X.`

What did the trick for me, was to uninstall Xcode 7.3 and install Xcode 6.2 from the Apple developer site.

Comment: Is this your answer or another question?

Comment: Replaced the question with the solution I found. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rename Xcode exists in your mac as Xcode-7.app in /Applications folder.
Then download Xcode6.4 from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and install it.

Comment: weirdly this worked for me. I had several versions of xcode on my computer but I needed to rename the original one for the xcode-select command to actually select the older compiler.

Answer (score 1):

### 80100 can work with some nvcc programs

I used "80100" and nvcc work for some of my other programs.

### ... but not sample

`

```
...
nvcc fatal   : The version ('80100') of the host compiler ('Apple clang') is not supported
...
```

`

### install CLT 8.2 (Command line tool from Apple) it is sort of ok with message about "command line tools instance"

I google and see a discussion about this (https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/issues/1384) [about array fire nvcc issue](https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/issues/1384) and thanks to the hint to switch to CLT 8.2, the last version not current one.  It is sort of ok with warning message about "command line tools instance"

Need to use "sudo make" to compile sample code:

`
    ...
    $ sudo make
    Password:

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
expr: syntax error

/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I../../common/inc  -m64  -Xcompiler -arch -Xcompiler x86_64  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=compute_60 -o deviceQuery.o -c deviceQuery.cpp

nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).

/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++   -m64  -Xcompiler -arch -Xcompiler x86_64  -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=compute_60 -o deviceQuery deviceQuery.o 

nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).

mkdir -p ../../bin/x86_64/darwin/release

cp deviceQuery ../../bin/x86_64/darwin/release

$ ./deviceQuery
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)
...
```

`

Comment: nvcc fatal : The version ('80100') of the host compiler ('Apple clang') is not supported. I am also having this error on OS X 10.12.4, Xcode 8.3 when compiling 3rd party lib (PCL) Are there any workarounds that anybody knows? I've tried different version of CLT with that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem! 
Looked in my Time Machine Backups and copied Xcode.app (7.2.1) in my /Application folder. You could also download it from the Apple Developer Page and move it into your /Application folder.
After it's done, you can change the Xcode Command Line Version in your Preferences of Xcode to 7.2.1
Then nvcc will work again (even with pycuda-2016.1).

`clang --version`

gives me:

`Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)`