# Building boost via homebrew hangs

Tags: python, macos, boost, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to get Caffe running on OS X 10.11 but have been having trouble building build boost from source via homebrew, as [the guide](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_osx.html) recommends. I have a fresh install of OS X with command-line tools, homebrew (python and python3 installed via homebrew) and all dependencies listed in the guide installed (built protobuf successfully). I am using MKL and CUDA 7.5.
After running the command

```
brew install --build-from-source -vd boost boost-python
```

the install script runs, shows configuration, and says
"...updating 13743 targets..."
then copies a bunch of files and says "...updated 13743 targets..."

It then hangs. It's been about two hours now, with Activity Monitor showing a ruby process that comes and goes taking about 85% of the CPU, with about 10% CPU in use by User. No gcc process. I've uploaded the full log [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5CvB-unqP4tYU9MVmtVbmlvbEk/view?usp=sharing). Am I just being impatient? Fresh OS X install gives the same result.

Comment: I've got the same issue, just a regular "brew update -v boost" is enough to get it to get stuck. Activity Monitor shows a Ruby process at around 85%. (Have you tried turning it off and on again? It's my best next bet. And letting through the 10.11.4 OS X update is also on my TODO)

Comment: Update to 10.11.4 did the trick. Note that if you're using Xcode (command-line tools) 7.3 you'll need to use the workaround here to downgrade the default clang version. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250949/revert-apple-clang-version-for-nvcc) (Find old Xcode apps at [link](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/))