# nvcc and clang are not working well together when installing pytorch-gpu

Tags: cuda, clang, pytorch, macos-sierra, nvcc

I am trying to install pytorch with gpu support on my MacBook Pro following official instructions.

Things go smoothly until an error occurred:

```
[ 70%] Building NVCC (Device) object caffe2/CMakeFiles/caffe2_gpu.dir/__/aten/src/THC/caffe2_gpu_generated_THCTensorMath.cu.o
nvcc fatal   : The version ('90000') of the host compiler ('Apple clang') is not supported
nvcc fatal   : The version ('90000') of the host compiler ('Apple clang') is not supported
CMake Error at caffe2_gpu_generated_THCBlas.cu.o.Release.cmake:219 (message):
  Error generating
  /Users/username/Dev/pytorch-gpu/pytorch/build/cCaMfafkee2 /ECrMraokre Faitle sc/acfaffef2e_2g_pgup_ug.ednierr/a_t_e/da_tTeHnC/Sslrece/pT.HcCu/..o/.cRaeflfeea2s_eg.pcum_agkeen:e2r1a9t e(dm_eTsHsCaBglea)s:.
```

It seems that CUDA and clang are not working well together.

I searched over internet and found these posts, but they did not solve my problem:

- [Revert Apple Clang Version For NVCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250949/revert-apple-clang-version-for-nvcc)
- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/3047

Here's my environment:

- macOS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G1618)
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M
- CUDA Driver Version: 387.178
- GPU Driver Version: 378.05.05.25f11
- Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61
- (Previous)Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
- (After downgrade)Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
- Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b)

Comment: What CUDA toolkit version are you using?

Comment: @talonmies Sorry, forgot the most important thing. Updated.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/8.0/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html#system-requirements) says that only Xcode 8.2 and its release compiler (8.000) is compatible with CUDA 8 on Sierra

Comment: @talonmies That is exactly what I am looking for. Tks.

Comment: If that lead you to a solution, please add an answer to this question

Comment: @talonmies As u suggested ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering my own question.

Incorrect CUDA installation on macOS could be  a nightmare. The versions of CUDA, Xcode, clang and macOS really matter. Here are some of the official tested ones:

```
+------+--------------+------------+---------------------------------+--------+
| CUDA |    Xcode     | Apple LLVM | Mac OSX Version (native x86_64) | Yes/No |
+------+--------------+------------+---------------------------------+--------+
| 8.0  | 7.2          | 7.0.3      | 10.11                           | YES    |
| 8.0  | 7.2          | 7.0.3      | 10.12                           | NO     |
| 8.0  | 8.2          | 8.0.0      | 10.11                           | NO     |
| 8.0  | 8.2          | 8.0.0      | 10.12                           | YES    |
| 9.0  | 8.3.3        | 8.1.0      | 10.12                           | YES    |
| 9.1  | 9.2          | 9.0.0      | 10.13.3                         | YES    |
| 9.2  | 9.2          | 9.0.0      | 10.13.5                         | YES    |
| 10.0 | 9.4          | 9.0.0      | 10.13.6                         | YES    |
| 10.1 | 10.1 (10B61) | 10.0.0     | 10.13.6 (17G2307)               | YES    |
+------+--------------+------------+---------------------------------+--------+
```

For CUDA Releases before 8.0, please search for *NVIDIA CUDA INSTALLATION GUIDE FOR MAC OS X* plus *the CUDA version number*, there should be a table of version matching in that PDF file.